# Draging camera to a limit (x, y axis) - UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, drag

i did a tutorial about doing a camera drag on a 2D or 3D worldmap.

The code is working. Looks like the following:

```cs
void Update_CameraDrag ()
{
    if( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) )
    {
        Debug.Log("Cancelling camera drag.");
        CancelUpdateFunc();
        return;
    }

    // Right now, all we need are camera controls

    Vector3 hitPos = MouseToGroundPlane(Input.mousePosition);
    //float maxWidth = 10;
    //if (hitPos.x > maxWidth)
    //{
    //    hitPos.x = maxWidth;
    //}
    Vector3 diff = lastMouseGroundPlanePosition - hitPos;

    Debug.Log(diff.x+ Space.World);

    Camera.main.transform.Translate (diff, Space.World);

    lastMouseGroundPlanePosition = hitPos = MouseToGroundPlane(Input.mousePosition);
}
```

Now my problem is, that you can drag unlimiited into any directions.
I would rather like to difine something like borders on the x and y axis.
Basically maximum values for the camera. If the camera would surpass these values, their position value would be set to the given maximum value.
Unfortunately, i am not sure how it works, especially, since the tutorial set everything into relation to Space.World - and i am not even sure what that is. I mean i understand that "diff" is the change between the current position and the new positon in relation to Space.World and then the camera gets moved accordingly. I would just like to define a max value which the camera can not surpass. Any ideas how to do that. I am unfortunately still learning - so kinda hard for me and i was hoping for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to record the X and Y position of the camera as it goes in a variable and use the MathF function. I.e

**if you have a map that is 100(x)x150(y)units you could use**

```
xPositionOfCamera = Mathf.Clamp(xPositionOfCamera, -50, 50);
yPositionOfCamera = Mathf.Clamp(YPositionOfCamera, -75, 75);
```

I'm not 100% sure if that's what you want it to do, but it's how I  would limit it.

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple and reliable script for my game to handle camera drag and swipe for any camera aspect ratio. Everyone can use this code easily :) Just adjust the xBoundWorld and  yBoundWorld values

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraDragController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 xBoundWorld;
    [SerializeField] private Vector2 yBoundWorld;
    [SerializeField] public bool HorizentalDrag = true;
    [SerializeField] public bool VerticalDrag = true;
    [SerializeField] public float speedFactor = 10;

    private float leftLimit;
    private float rightLimit;
    private float topLimit;
    private float downLimit;

    public bool allowDrag = true;
    private void Start()
    {
        CalculateLimitsBasedOnAspectRatio();
    }

    public void UpdateBounds(Vector2 xBoundNew, Vector2 yBoundNew)
    {
        xBoundWorld = xBoundNew;
        yBoundWorld = yBoundNew;
        CalculateLimitsBasedOnAspectRatio();
    }

    private void CalculateLimitsBasedOnAspectRatio()
    {
        leftLimit = xBoundWorld.x - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).x;
        rightLimit = xBoundWorld.y - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 0, 0)).x;
        downLimit = yBoundWorld.x - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, 0)).y;
        topLimit = yBoundWorld.y - Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 1, 0)).y;
    }

    Vector3 lastPosView; // we use viewport because we don't want devices pixel density affect our swipe speed
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (allowDrag)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                lastPosView = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            }
            else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                var newPosView = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
                var cameraMovment = (lastPosView - newPosView) * speedFactor;
                lastPosView = newPosView;

                cameraMovment = Limit2Bound(cameraMovment);

                if (HorizentalDrag)
                    Camera.main.transform.Translate(new Vector3(cameraMovment.x, 0, 0));
                if (VerticalDrag)
                    Camera.main.transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, cameraMovment.y, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 Limit2Bound(Vector3 distanceView)
    {
        if (distanceView.x < 0) // Check left limit
        {
            if (Camera.main.transform.position.x + distanceView.x < leftLimit)
            {
                distanceView.x = leftLimit - Camera.main.transform.position.x;
            }
        }
        else // Check right limit
        {
            if (Camera.main.transform.position.x + distanceView.x > rightLimit)
            {
                distanceView.x = rightLimit - Camera.main.transform.position.x;
            }
        }

        if (distanceView.y < 0) // Check down limit
        {
            if (Camera.main.transform.position.y + distanceView.y < downLimit)
            {
                distanceView.y = downLimit - Camera.main.transform.position.y;
            }
        }
        else // Check top limit
        {
            if (Camera.main.transform.position.y + distanceView.y > topLimit)
            {
                distanceView.y = topLimit - Camera.main.transform.position.y;
            }
        }

        return distanceView;
    }
}
```